# Significance of 'flags' option in createReadStreams/createWriteStreams of Node.js?

Tags: node.js, filesystems, fs

What is the significance of 'flags' option of `fs.createReadStream/createWritStream` while `ReadStream` and `WriteStream` of `fs` module are self-explanatory whether they are readable or writable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag option allows you to set different behaviour related to writing or overwriting files.

For example, when creating a `WriteStream`, if you pass the flag `w` it will overwrite the file if it exists (this is the default value), whereas if you use the flag `r+`, it will just modify the file if it exists as it actually open the files for reading and writing or will have an error if it doesnt exist.

Here is a lost of flags and there explanation:

```
'r' - Open file for reading. An exception occurs if the file does not exist.
'r+' - Open file for reading and writing. An exception occurs if the file does not exist.
'w' - Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).
'w+' - Open file for reading and writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).
'a' - Open file for appending. The file is created if it does not exist.
'a+' - Open file for reading and appending. The file is created if it does not exist.
```